# Draw a path in AndEngine to move a image or sprite

Tags: android, path, andengine

hi am new in Android game development i use AndEngine i need to ploat a path but there is a problem[image]

look at the image.The path i need is like the first one the object should move from the bottom to the middle of the screen.but while i plot my path it move to the middle of the screen but goes back to the 2nd point as in the Second image.The image is moving through the path but it is like the 2nd image.i need it as the first one.it should stop in the 3rd point and should start from the first point again.

My code is given below

```
package com.example.sss;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.IEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.LoopEntityModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier.IPathModifierListener;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier.Path;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.RepeatingSpriteBackground;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import   org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;

/**
 * (c) 2010 Nicolas Gramlich
 * (c) 2011 Zynga
  *
 * @author Nicolas Gramlich
* @since 13:58:48 - 19.07.2010
 */
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private RepeatingSpriteBackground mGrassBackground;

private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private TiledTextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================


public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
}


public void onCreateResources() {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 128, 128);
    this.mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "player.png", 0, 0, 3, 4);
    this.mGrassBackground = new RepeatingSpriteBackground(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.getTextureManager(), AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(this.getAssets(), "gfx/background_grass.png"), this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
}


public Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    final Scene scene_one = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(this.mGrassBackground);




    /* Calculate the coordinates for the face, so its centered on the camera.     */
    final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
    System.out.println("aaaaaa"+centerX+"asdadas");

    /* Create the sprite and add it to the scene. */
    final AnimatedSprite player_one = new AnimatedSprite(centerX, centerY, 48, 64, this.mPlayerTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    final Path path_one =  new Path(5).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, 10).to(10, 10).to(100, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2f);//to(10, 10).to(10, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 74).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 74).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, 10).to(10, 10);
    final AnimatedSprite player = new AnimatedSprite(centerX, centerY, 48, 64, this.mPlayerTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    final Path path = new Path(5).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, 10).to(10, 10).to(10, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2f);


    player.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(5, path, null, new IPathModifierListener() {

        public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {

        }


        public void onPathWaypointStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {
            switch(pWaypointIndex) {
                case 0:
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 6, 8, true);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 0, 2, true);


                    break;
                case 3:
                    //scene.setVisible(false);
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 9, 11, true);
                    break;
            }
        }


        public void onPathWaypointFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {



        }


        public void onPathFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
            System.out.println("tileesdfsdfsdfgfdgdfsee"+player.getCurrentTileIndex() );
        }
    })));
















player_one.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(5, path_one,    null, new IPathModifierListener() {

        public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final   IEntity pEntity) {

        }


        public void onPathWaypointStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier,   final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {
            switch(pWaypointIndex) {
                case 0:
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 6, 8, true);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);


                    break;
                case 2:
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 0, 2, true);

                         System.out.println("insideeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                    scene.detachChild(player_one);
                    scene.attachChild(player);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 9, 11, true);
                    break;
            }
        }


        public void onPathWaypointFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {



        }


        public void onPathFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
            System.out.println("tileesdfsdfsdfgfdgdfsee"+player.getCurrentTileIndex() );
        }
    })));






    scene.attachChild(player);

    return scene;
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================
}
```

please help me.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have three points you should specify it in your Path constructor:

```
final Path path = new Path(3).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, 10).to(10, 10).to(10, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2f);
```

instead

```
final Path path = new Path(5).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, 10).to(10, 10).to(10, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2f);
```

Comment: driver613  do you know the solution for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755693/how-to-fall-a-sprite-over-another-using-and-engine-in-android

Comment: no it not working for me .do you have any example codes for that question thank you.