# How to fall a sprite over another using And engine in android?

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

Hi how can i put a one sprite over another sprite as seen in the image below [image]

as you can seen there is two sprite in the image (1).The sprite in the top should place over the sprite in the bottom as seen in the image (3).I tried some And engine example but did not get any solution yet .If any one know how to handle this problem please find some solution or any source.Thanks in advance

Attaching code as per the edit

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private static final int LAYER_COUNT = 4;
 Scene scene;
// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

private Camera mCamera;

private Font mFont;

private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private ITextureRegion mBadgeTextureRegion;
private ITextureRegion mNextTextureRegion;

private static final IEaseFunction[][] EASEFUNCTIONS = new IEaseFunction[][]{
    new IEaseFunction[] {
            EaseLinear.getInstance(),
            EaseLinear.getInstance(),
            EaseLinear.getInstance()
    },

};

private int mCurrentEaseFunctionSet = 0;

private final Sprite[] mBadges = new Sprite[1];
//private final Text[] mEaseFunctionNameTexts = new Text[3];

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================


public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);
}


public void onCreateResources() {
    /* The font. */
    final ITexture fontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mFont = new Font(this.getFontManager(), fontTexture, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32, true, Color.WHITE);
    this.mFont.load();

    /* The textures. */
    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    this.mNextTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "next.png", 0, 0);
    this.mBadgeTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "badge.png", 97, 0);

    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
}


public Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

scene = new Scene();



    /* Create the sprites that will be moving. */

    this.mBadges[0] = new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 300, this.mBadgeTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());


    scene.attachChild(this.mBadges[0]);

    return scene;
}


public void onGameCreated() {

    this.reanimate();
    }








// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================


private void reanimate() {
    this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            final IEaseFunction[] currentEaseFunctionsSet = EASEFUNCTIONS[MainActivity.this.mCurrentEaseFunctionSet];
        //  final Text[] easeFunctionNameTexts = MainActivity.this.mEaseFunctionNameTexts;
            final Sprite[] faces = MainActivity.this.mBadges;


            //  easeFunctionNameTexts[i].setText(currentEaseFunctionsSet[i].getClass().getSimpleName());
                final Sprite face = faces[0];

                face.clearEntityModifiers();

                final float y = face.getY();
                face.setPosition(0, y);
                face.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(3, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH - face.getWidth(), y, y, currentEaseFunctionsSet[0]));

        }
    });
}

// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code!

```
this.mBadges[1] = new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 300, this.mBadgeTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());


scene.attachChild(this.mBadges[1]);
this.mBadges[1].setPosition(positionX, mBadges[0].getY()-mBadges[1].getHeight());
```

Whatever your positionX is replace it by that.

Comment: yes exactly i am trying to making an image fall down onto another

Comment: Then your picture is a bit misleading. This pretty simple, first create the two sprites and then use the sprite.setPosition(positionX,(CameraHeight-sprite1.getHeight()-sprite2.getHeight())). PositionX can be whatever you choose. There's a fair chance that I've misunderstood your problem since it was an easy one, if this is the case feel free to ask :)

Comment: can you please show some code i dont under stand the answer clearly

Comment: hey i have attach the code not sure my code is correct if it not as my question plaese provide some solution Thank you

Comment: did you apply this on my code? because when i apply it show a error in set position

Comment: Sorry forgot to add positionX, check it now. Replace positionX by the X postion of sprite.

Comment: Ramz, the code should be posted here for other people to see. You should not request personal emails on SO, the code should be here so that everyone can benefit, not only you.